# Integrate instamojo api in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-3, payment-gateway

I am learning payment gateway integration in rails.
I chose insta mojo and was working but the documentation they provide is very inconvenient and hard to understand..

https://github.com/AnkurGel/Instamojo-rb#usage

I have no idea where to Set my API keys

```
require 'Instamojo-rb'
api = Instamojo::API.new do |app|
  app.api_key = "api_key-you-received-from-api@instamojo.com"
  app.auth_token = "auth_token-you-received-from-api@instamojo.com"
end`
```

I tried instamojo.rb in initializers and tries to run console but it gives error that no such method exists.

Comment: I have also integrated Instamojo Payments with my Project and so far it is working fine for me. 
By the way which 'method' are you trying to access in console? Can you add that command to your question for better clarification?

Comment: could you please give me a very small tutorial in brief of how to do, cz documentation is not clear and I want to learn.

Comment: I have added the sample of how to use the API, check out the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can put require statement in application.rb or anywhere else so that file is loaded while application is loading.
2. You can make 'Payment' model in which you can make methods like verify and get details.
3. Internally in those methods, you will be making API object and using the above code.

   ```
   class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

     def verify
       client = get_intamojo_client
       #Some code
     end

     def get_details
       client = get_intamojo_client
       #Some code
     end

     private

     def get_instamojo_client
       api = Instamojo::API.new(ENV["INSTAMOJO_KEY"],{auth_token: ENV["INSTAMOJO_TOKEN"], endpoint:"https://test.instamojo.com/api/1.1/"})
       return api.client
     end

   end
   ```

And to explore what you can do using client object, just use rails console and make a client object there, and use `client.public_methods` and start exploring.

EDIT:

I think you are using older version of gem i.e 0.1, their documentation is for version > 1.0. To update, use this `gem 'Instamojo-rb', '~> 1.1'` in gem file and use bundle update.

So for version 0.1, use

```
api = Instamojo::API.new(ENV["INSTAMOJO_KEY"],{auth_token: ENV["INSTAMOJO_TOKEN"], endpoint:"https://test.instamojo.com/api/1.1/"})
```

And for versino >= 1.0, use

```
api = Instamojo::API.new(ENV["INSTAMOJO_KEY"], ENV["INSTAMOJO_TOKEN"], "https://test.instamojo.com/api/1.1/")
```

Comment: I tried the command in console - client = api.client but it says ; 
undefined local variable or method `api' for main:Object
Did you mean?  app

Comment: first make api object in console too, don't rely on initializer, because it will make a local object only while loading initializer file.

Comment: also, in my form submit button( after which I want to initialize the payment, what shall I call in my create method to call this API and initialize payment process.

Comment: thanx, I will try making an api in console

Comment: check out the updated code as their documentation of gem seems outdated.

Comment: You need to explore how can you make requests using this. Yes this certainly will require auth token also.  But where, that is you need to explore.

Comment: how can I call payment model's method from my User Controller to redirect to instamojo gateway?

Comment: https://docs.instamojo.com/docs/sdk

Try checkout.js for that. I'm also using this instead of managing payments on my back end. I just verify the payment status after their gateway redirects user to my site after payment.

Comment: @AlaapDhall try new edited code which also takes auth_token and end point. In this way you can make client object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158759/discussion-between-aakash-gupta-and-alaap-dhall).